# How can I write a Watir conditional loop to click the "OK" button if a JavaScript popup opens?

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir

So in certain test cases, my application will throw a JavaScript pop-up indication that no more letters can be written for the month, which interrupts my Watir automation.

Is there a way to catch a javascript pop-up using Watir, to then click the "OK" button and move on?

This is what I have so far:

```
# Send New Letter
browser.link(:class,'new-message-button').click
browser.frame(:id,'letterText_ifr').click

javascript_dialog.button('OK').click # <= I need help here with conditional

browser.send_keys 'This is a test'
browser.button(:id,'send-button').click
browser.link(:id,'sign_out').click
```

Comment: Do you have access to the javascript you're running? Can you prevent the popup from appearing by doing something like `window.alert = function(){};`?

Comment: Well, if it does pop up, I want to recognize it in the conditional and click the OK button.  Once that happens it would have to ignore the rest of the code following the OK click, `browser.send_keys "This is a test"...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you tried something like expecting the JS dialog to be here, and rescuing it (if that fails) with the code to send the letter?

```
browser.frame(:id,'letterText_ifr').click_no_wait
begin
  javascript_dialog.button('OK').click # <= I need help here with conditional
rescue
  browser.send_keys 'This is a test'
  browser.button(:id,'send-button').click
end
browser.link(:id,'sign_out').click
```

it's not very elegant, but it might do what you need

Comment: Your code appears to solve the problem to a degree, but after the JavaScript popup OK button is clicked, Watir doesn't seem to know how to get back to the browser to continue with the test to click the log out link.

Comment: The browser should still be there, I'm not sure what you mean by 'get back to the browser'   but without having access to your site, it's hard for me to guess what might be going on at that point

Comment: In the comments to your question you said 'ignore the rest of the code following the OK click'  if that is not what you want, and what you want is 'don't try to send an email, and continue with the logout click' then you need to move that bit of code out of the rescue section so it will always be executed.   I'll edit the answer to reflect that (presuming I now understand what you really want, which is not ignoring the rest of the code if the dialog is present

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but the obvious answer would seem to be:

```
javascript_dialog.button('OK').click if javascript_dialog.button('OK').exists?
```

Comment: I think the issue here would be that he needs conditional logic not just to click the dialog if it is there, but also to send a test email if he can

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Anyway maybe that helps with the condition. exists? is probably what you want. Possible exists? and visible?

Answer (score 1):

If the time of the dialog appearance is not random, but very well known/defined, you can use some of these:

```
until javascript_dialog.button('OK').exists? do 
    sleep 1 
end 
javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

or

```
sleep 1 until javascript_dialog.button('OK').exists?
javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

or

```
javascript_dialog.button('OK').when_present.click
```

or

```
javascript_dialog.button('OK').wait_until_present
javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I would attempt to click the the button in the JavaScript popup, Ruby would loose the focus of the browser and crash.

I ended up just ignoring the error and signing-out to rerun the test on another individual who may not have sent a letter yet.  (The 30th of April is within this week, so it would cause the alert to show) See new code below:

```
if browser.text.include?('30-Apr')
  browser.link(:id,'sign_out').click
else
  browser.send_keys 'This is a test'
  browser.button(:id,'send-button').click
end
```

Comment: this seems strange if it really is a modal javascript alert, usually you'd not be able to interact with the browser until you dismissed it.  I wonder if you are actually seeing some other kind of popup and the error was because it could not find a javascript alert to click on.    If the '30-april' text you were looking for is part of the alert text, that would be another indicator that you are looking at some construct that is part of the DOM, not a javascript alert